# How to validate RadAutoCompleteBox in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I bound the `ItemSource` to `RadAutoCompleteBox` and the data is bound to the `RadAutoCompleteBox`. But I am struggling with validating the `RadAutoCompleteBox`.

If any invalid data (other than the `ItemSource`) is entered, it takes the `selectedItem` as null.
If I don't enter any value into the box, it also takes the `selectedItem` as null. I want to differentiate between them.

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the RadAutoCompleteBox SearchText property. The SearchText does not return the AutoCompleteBox items, instead it returns the plain text you are entering in the AutoCompleteBox.

Comment: Hi, i am new to wpf.. if u dont mind, can u give me an explanation or demo for this.